# How to have an "export default" with multiple types and values in a TypeScript module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, es6-modules

I can easily have an export default with multiple values:

```
class Car {...}
class Bus {...}

export default { Car, Bus }
```

I can also easily have an export default of a type

```
export default interface Airplane {...}
```

But I can't have a default export of multiple types

```
interface Airplane {...}
interface Motorcycle {...}

// 'Airplane' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
export default { Airplane, Motorcycle }
```

Or of a mix of multiple types and values.

```
class Car {...}
interface Motorcycle {...}

// 'Airplane' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
export default { Car, Airplane }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't mix types and values in a default export object. Why do you want to do this? Default exports objects in general are considered by some (including myself) as harmful. Just export each thing individually.

Comment: There is a `prefer-default-export` linting rule. Airbnb would disagree with you it seems: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1365

Comment: Yes, some (including myself) disagree with Airbnb on this. Also to note, exporting a bunch of stuff on an object breaks the spirit of Airbnb's rule to export a single thing per file (which I actually agree with, I just disagree with using default at all due to harm it causes).

Comment: I think the spirit of Airbnb's rule is to avoid multiple exports per file (an object/namespace containing multiple things is still only one export), although I might be wrong. Anyway, I guess you can post your answer, which is "You can't mix types and values in a default export object".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple exports per file, as long as there's no default export.

Comment: Rather than asking why the OP wants to do this, why not answer the question, why does TS disallow this?  Seems like such a comment might be more useful, rather than deflecting the question down a rabbit hole of opinions.  In the meantime I'll assume the reason no one explained why TS disallows this, is because there's no good reason and it is simply a shortcoming of the language.

Answer (score 7):

Consider `export =` syntax.

The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.

---

Vehicle.ts

```
namespace Vehicle {
    export class Car {
        // ...
    }

    export class Bus {
        // ...
    }
}

export = Vehicle;
```

Test1.ts

```
import Vehicle from './Vehicle';

const car = new Vehicle.Car();
const bus = new Vehicle.Bus();
```

Test2.ts

```
import { Bus, Car } from './Vehicle';

const car = new Car();
const bus = new Bus();
```

---

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

Comment: But this isn't the same as `export default`...

Comment: Of course it's different. But this syntax solves the problem described in the question.  

Another issue is that this syntax is only supported by the "СommonJS" and "AMD" modules.
I see that many libraries are now moving to ESM where this syntax will not work.
So it is better not to use this syntax and look towards ESM.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, by exporting like so:

```
class Car {...}
interface Motorcycle {...}

// 'Airplane' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. ts(2693)
export default { Car, Airplane }
```

What you do is to **export a default object with two properties*.*

Later, in your code, you can import it like so:

```
// name is as you like, its default import
import transport from transport;
```

and use it like so:

```
....new transport.Car()
....new transport.Plane()
```